# single controller managing a model and multiple viewcontrollers?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, model-view-controller

I'm working on an app that has multiple view controllers for different screens and the whole app is about displaying data from an sqlite db.

My inicial design was to have a db object (the model), a main controller with exclusive access to this model and have all other view controllers merely manage visual aspects of windows,buttons,whathaveyou.

But I'm having a hard time realizing how to make the main controller be aware of all other view controllers throughout the app's life in the context of apple's ios app architecture.

I've thought of 3 approaches so far:
1 - NSNotificationCenter and have the main controller observe all other controllers? 
2 - make the main controller delegate of all others? Though I'm still not clear on how to define a delegable (did I make this word up?) protocol in general. That is, even for objects that don't have a setDelegate method.
3 - passing an db object around to each view controller. Though this seems a bit like playing C passing state around..

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach should probably be one where the view controllers and models are as ignorant of each other as possible. This is a pretty common design pattern, I believe. You should have model objects that represent each logical "object" in your domain. Those objects may just be state. Next, you might want to create a controller (like you mentioned) that has access to your database and can make queries. The result of those queries should be used to construct instances of your logical model objects (e.g., XXPerson) and hand them off to whatever made the query. Given that, each view controller in your app should do the following:

1. Create its views and lay them out as appropriate
2. Instantiate your database controller object (and possibly hold on to it for further use)
3. Query the database for the data it needs via the database controller object
4. Use the resulting data (which should be returned as your logical model objects) to adjust the views or do whatever you need with them

Note that you *could* make use of a singleton for your database controller, but the singleton pattern is a loathsome one if you ask most good developers. :) Instead, there's really no reason why your application can't just create an instance of your database controller as needed, use it for some queries, then discard it afterwards.

Internally, of course, your database controller class should have singular, static access to the database and possibly synchronize access to write methods so that you don't run into issues with concurrency.

There are many possible design approaches, but one in which things are loosely coupled means that there isn't a bunch of interdependency going on, which is always a good thing. Let your model objects, database controller objects, and views all be independent of each other. The view controllers, of course, are the bridges that tie all those independent concepts together into a functional product.

That's my opinion, anyway. :)

Comment: Agreed, just keep in mind that your controller code is usually the least reusable portion of your App.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a Data Access Object or service/store as part of your controller layer. I think that's a good idea and a common pattern in other languages that for some reason seems widely ignored in iOS apps.

Provide each of your view controllers with some object which manages access to your data store. You might want to only construct a single instance of that store but your controller's don't need to know that. As far as any individual controller is concerned it was given an object it can use to get and store model objects.

I don't think you should try to prevent your view controllers from accessing model objects at all. Rather introduce a service so that your view controllers don't need to know the details of how to load or persist those model objects. If necessary you can use that service to translate between one model and another if you find the need for a view-model or don't want your view controllers to work directly with whatever model objects you persist.

I think that a dependency like this should be a strong reference rather than a delegate and provided to each view controller when they are constructed via constructor-based or property-based dependency injection or some inversion of control container as appropriate for your app.